# Need script to take comma-separated values across all rows in spreadsheet and substitute with values from 2nd spreadsheet based on a search

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am creating a calendaring/scheduling resource. The user inputs all calendaring/event data in a Google Form. Each time a form is submitted, the data populates to a "Form Responses" spreadsheet, where a new row is created.  From within the spreadsheet, the spreadsheet owner can run a script to create Google Calendar entries.

Among the data collected through the Google Form, the user can choose from among 100+ calendars upon which he would like his event information to appear. So, for example, he can choose from among calendar names such as "Apple", "Pear", "Watermelon", and "Orange" from a list of over 100 calendars. In the spreadsheet, these selections would appears in a comma-separated list: apple, pear, watermelon, orange.

In a separate "resource" spreadsheet, I have two columns. Column 1 contains the above calendar names, and Column 2 contains the corresponding Google Calendar resource address.

COL A

A1 Apple

A2 Pear

A3 Watermelon

A4 Orange

COL B

B1 domain.com_190382d0931@resource.calendar.google.com

B2 domain.com_928313sdf98@resource.calendar.google.com

B3 domain.com_239829a3l18@resource.calendar.google.com

B4 domain.com_295801a0181@resource.calendar.google.com

I need a script that reads the user-submitted calendar name data in the "Form Responses" spreadsheet, searches the "Resources" Spreadsheet for the same data, and returns the substituted Google Calendar resource addresses in a comma-separated value in a designated column in the "Form Responses" spreadsheet.

Example:

User 1 submits data that he wants to book his event on Calendars "Pear" and "Apple"

User 2 submits data that he wants to book his event on Calendars "Orange" and "Apple"

User 3 submits data that he wants to book his event on Calendars "Pear", "Apple", and "Orange"

In "Form Responses" spreadsheet, three rows of data are created. One column contains the calendar data for each submission.

So:

J2 contains Pear, Apple

J3 contains Orange, Apple

J4 contains Pear, Apple, Orange

I want a column at the end of the Form Responses spreadsheet to populate with the resource equivalents, as pulled from the "Resource" spreadsheet.

So:

Z2 contains domain.com_928313sdf98@resource.calendar.google.com, domain.com_190382d0931@resource.calendar.google.com

Z3 contains domain.com_295801a0181@resource.calendar.google.com, domain.com_190382d0931@resource.calendar.google.com

Z4 contains domain.com_928313sdf98@resource.calendar.google.com, domain.com_190382d0931@resource.calendar.google.com, 
domain.com_295801a0181@resource.calendar.google.com

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to manage with arrays.

1. take you cell with comma separated values and split it on commas (which is the default split element). For example : `var calNamestoWrite = cell.split(',');` and you'll get an array of `n` elements
2. read you second sheet using `getValues()` so that you get a 2D array of as much elements as rows in sheet2. 
   For example : `var calNames = ss.sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();`

Then in a double for loop you can simply check the calendar names by comparing

```
if(calNamestoWrite[n]==calNames[c][0]){ var calID = calNames[c][1] ... and do the other stuf...}
```

since the first column was the name and the second was the calendar ressource id.

`n` iterates the `calNamestoWrite` array and `c` iterates the array from sheet2.

et voilà, this would take you a couple of minutes to write.